# laravel vue inertia paginator remove prev and next links

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

Im trying to remove prev and next links from array. Using laravel vue3 inertiajs.

```
const splicedlinks = computed(() => {
    let prevIndex = props.links.meta.links
        .map((link) => link.label)
        .indexOf("&laquo; Previous");
    let nextIndex = props.links.meta.links
        .map((link) => link.label)
        .indexOf("Next &raquo;");

    props.links.meta.links.splice(prevIndex, 1);
    props.links.meta.links.splice(nextIndex, 1);

    return props.links.meta.links;
});
```

With this code i managed only to remove "« Previous", but not "Next »"

[navigation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axhrf.png)

Whats wrong with my code?

i explained what i tried in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the index of the "Next" element was changed after the first "splice" using.

JS Array splice method affects the source array. So the found elements indexes are not relevant after deleting an element by "splice" method.

You should to find "nextIndex" after deleting an element by "prevIndex"

**Try this:**

```
const splicedlinks = computed(() => {
    let prevIndex = props.links.meta.links
        .map((link) => link.label)
        .indexOf("&laquo; Previous");

    // Remove "Previous" button
    props.links.meta.links.splice(prevIndex, 1);

    // After "Previous" button deleting find index of "Next" button
    let nextIndex = props.links.meta.links
        .map((link) => link.label)
        .indexOf("Next &raquo;");
    
    // Remove "Next" button
    props.links.meta.links.splice(nextIndex, 1);

    return props.links.meta.links;
});
```

Also, you can simplify your code by using "findIndex" methods instead indexOf

**Example:**

```
let nextIndex = props.links.meta.links?.findIndex((link) => link.label === "Next &raquo;");
```

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation and the code. Works!